# Cannot assign to value: 'setText' is a method

Tags: swift

Im using Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a) and Swift to make an iPhone and Apple Watch app I have some code that has made a simple timer label and start and stop buttons and Id like to also have that on the Apple Watch.

In the Xcode viewcontroller.swift file I have this code and it works great.

```
var startTime = TimeInterval()
var startofTime = Date()
var timer:Timer = Timer()
var endTime: Date!

@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Start: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Stop: UIButton!

@IBAction func startAct(_ sender: Any) {
        alarmTime = Date()
        startofTime = Date()
        Start.isHidden = true
        Stop.isHidden = false
        if (!timer.isValid) {
            let aSelector : Selector = #selector(ViewController.updateTime)
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            startTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        }
        }



@IBAction func stopAction(_ sender: Any) {
        progressView.progress = 0.0
        progress.completedUnitCount = 1024
        Start.isHidden = false
        Stop.isHidden = true
        endTime = Date()
        timer.invalidate()
}

@objc func updateTime() {
    let currentTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

    //Find the difference between current time and start time.
    var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

    // print(elapsedTime)
    //  print(Int(elapsedTime))

    //calculate the hours in elapsed time.
    let hours = UInt8(elapsedTime / 3600.0)
    elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(hours) * 3600)

    //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.
    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
    elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

    //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.
    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
    elapsedTime -= TimeInterval(seconds)

    //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.
    let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

    //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants

    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
    let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", fraction)

    //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel
    timerLabel.text = "\(hours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds).\(strFraction)"

}
```

When I tried to copy it to the watch InterfaceController.swift I got most of it done by just coping and pasting but I get a error about the label.

!Cannot assign to value: 'setText' is a method

Can anyone help me with the label for the watch. Something like this -

```
timerLabel.setText = "\(hours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds).\(strFraction)"
```

if I just put

```
timerLabel.setText((strFraction))
```

It works to display the milliseconds but id like to combine them all please.

If I do this

```
timerLabel.setText((strSeconds)(strFraction))
```

I get this error

!Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'

This is the full watch code so far, just need the last line

```
//
//  InterfaceController.swift
//  WatchKit Extension
//
//  Created by Kurt on 3/10/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Kurt. All rights reserved.
//

import WatchKit
import Foundation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

    var startTime = TimeInterval()
    var startofTime = Date()
    var timer:Timer = Timer()
    var endTime: Date!

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    @IBAction func Start() {

        startofTime = Date()

        if (!timer.isValid) {
            let aSelector : Selector = #selector(InterfaceController.updateTime)
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            startTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        }
    }

    @objc func updateTime() {
        let currentTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

        //Find the difference between current time and start time.
        var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

        // print(elapsedTime)
        //  print(Int(elapsedTime))

        //calculate the hours in elapsed time.
        let hours = UInt8(elapsedTime / 3600.0)
        elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(hours) * 3600)

        //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.
        let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
        elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

        //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.
        let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
        elapsedTime -= TimeInterval(seconds)

        //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.
        let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

        //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants

        let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
        let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
        let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", fraction)

        //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel

       timerLabel.setText(\(hours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds).\(strFraction)) !error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as,

```
timerLabel.setText("\(hours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds).\(strFraction)")
```

Comment: I get this error !Cannot convert value of type '(String, String)' to expected argument type 'String?'

Comment: @KurtLane Please copy and paste the above line i provided. In your code, you are missing the quote (") around the string.

Comment: oh thanks, its fixed, I tried so many times my eyes are going bad

Answer (score 0):

The `setText` method isn't available for the `UILabel` class in Swift.

Assuming you've created a `setText` extension method to the `UILabel` class,

you can do it this way:

`timerLabel.setText("\(hours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds).\(strFraction)")`

Comment: on the watch app I get the error !Value of type 'WKInterfaceLabel' has no member 'text' and !Cannot convert value of type '(String, String)' to expected argument type 'String?'

Answer (score 0):

For UILabel, `text` is a property & `:setText` is setter method for this property. So either use this property as:

```
timerLabel.text = "\(hours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds).\(strFraction)"
```

Or, use setter method as:

```
timerLabel.setText("\(hours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds).\(strFraction)")
```

But for iWatch, `WKInterfaceLabel` does not have any text property. You can only change the text at runtime using `:setText` method. For more info: [see here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacelabel)

[image]

Comment: for the watch app I get the error !Value of type 'WKInterfaceLabel' has no member 'text'

Comment: `WKInterfaceLabel` do not have text property, it is only for iOS and tvOS

Answer (score 0):

The setText method isn't available for the UILabel class in Swift. You can use text propriety of UILabel.

```
timerLabel.text = "\(hours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds).\(strFraction)"
```

Comment: on the watch app I get the error !Value of type 'WKInterfaceLabel' has no member 'text' and !Cannot convert value of type '(String, String)' to expected argument type 'String?'